# UserControl Parent window- when this UserControl is being used in multiple Windows

Tags: wpf, windows, user-controls

I have User-control in `WPF`. This is supposed to be used in multiple Windows. I want to get current Parent Window at run-time.

In User-control code-behind file following line is being used.

`MyWindow1 parentWindow = (MyWindow1)Window.GetWindow(this);`

What if the same `UserControl` wud be used in `MyWindow2`? Above line would not be correct in this case. Any suggession?

Comment: Welocme to StackOverflow.Please read the FAQ before asking questions and Please make sure that your question is clear and perfect to be understood by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this although I don't think it's a very nice code-design to have child controls reference parents in such a way.

If you have your justifications for such a requirement you can do something like this in your say `UserControl`'s constructor

```
  Loaded += (sender, args) => {
    Window win = Window.GetWindow(this);
    if (win == null)
      return;
    if (win is MyWindow1) {
      MessageBox.Show("Window 1");
    } else if (win is MyWindow2) {
      MessageBox.Show("Window 2");
    }
  };
```

Your basically using the `is` operator to check the type and then perform your action. Again I would recommend not going down this route unless you have a very compelling reason to.

Comment: Is there any other better way to get the same req?

Comment: You should try to rework your requirement. You'd want your setup in such a way that the child does not know much about the parent if possible. You can say have a DP in the user control that could be assigned with a binding from the parent. Based on this DP you can modify the UserControl's behavior. It will then de-couple the UserControl from such a close relationship and allow it to be expanded individually.

Comment: Above solution is right but i need to call current window methods n properties, how can i do this as i have to cast the Window into specific Window.

Comment: I don't follow your requirement. Yes you do need to cast if you want to call your window's method or parameters. But if both MyWindow1 and MyWindow2 have the same method / parameters that the UserControl needs, Then you should derive both windows from a common base class consisting of these methods & parameters. This way the UserControl can just cast the Window to the base class type and call the methods / parameters without being specific to which particular window type.